# Why is there 200 GB's of space belonging to "Untitled" on my Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, storage

So basically my Macbook Pro (2015 Model) has been giving me a lot of issues recently. Yesterday it kept force restarting on me and I had to factory reset it to get it to stop. Well, I guess I messed up the factory reset because I no longer have a Mac HD drive on my computer, only a bootcamp drive. This bootcamp drive only has 50 GB's of storage for use, it says the other 200 is "untitled" when I go into disk utility. Is there anyway I can fix this?

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you want to erase and start over?

Comment: As usual, paste the output of those commands: ```diskutil list```, ```diskutil apfs list```, and ```gpt show /dev/rdisk0```